# cuda version, and pytorch version

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I have this error in google colab:

```
RuntimeError: 
The detected CUDA version (12.2) mismatches the version that was used to compile
PyTorch (11.8). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

These are my cuda and torch versions:

cuda version:

```
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_15_22:02:13_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.140
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.33191640_0
```

This is the pytorch version: 
2.0.1+cu118

I tried to install cuda 11.8 but it didn't work.