# Getting CUDA version correctly reported by nvcc

Tags: pytorch, cuda, nvcc, nvidia-smi

I am trying to update CUDA in Ubuntu.  Following the guide [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu), my initial set up had the CUDA version reported as:

- via nvcc - Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
- via nvidia-smi - 11.1

After the error free update the CUDA versions were reported as:

- via nvcc - Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
- via nvidia-smi - 12.1

The difficulty this causes is that when I try to install say, `torch-cluster` I get an error:

```
RuntimeError:
      The detected CUDA version (10.1) mismatches the version that was used to compile
      PyTorch (11.7). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

Based on recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470424/nvcc-missing-when-installing-cudatoolkit), I expressly downloaded and installed the Toolkit v11.7 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-7-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=18.04&target_type=deb_local) and tried to do an install but got this message:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (12.1.1-1).
```

But nvcc continues to report:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

How do I resolve this? ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77075281/cuda-version-and-pytorch-version) may be a similar question that isn't answered yet)

Comment: How did you install the cuda-toolkit? Did you perform the necessary post-installation steps, if any?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: @RobertCrovella that is the link I referred to in the first line of my question.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor if you mean reboot and 5.8/5.9 of the installation guide, yes.  Also before installation I did a purge.

Comment: did you do the mandatory steps listed in section 13?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I ran mandatory 13.1.1

Comment: `nvidia-smi` doesn't report the version of the installed CUDA Toolkit. It reports the maximum version supported by the driver. I.e. you seem to have updated the driver but not the SDK.

Comment: what is recommended way to backtrack to install SDK if I have a successful driver installation?  Or is it just purge and start over ie. `sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cuda*" "*cublas*" "*cufft*" "*cufile*" "*curand*" "*cusolver*" "*cusparse*" "*gds-tools*" "*npp*" "*nvjpeg*" "nsight*"`

Comment: So you did step 13.1.1 and after you were done with that, `nvcc -V` indicated 10.1?  If so, you didn't do step 13.1.1 correctly.  Your `PATH` variable determines which version of `nvcc` will be found/used when you type `nvcc ...`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella based on your observations I looked at my $PATH.  I modified my OP to reflect what I found.

Comment: Well, it seems that now you have found out how to update the CUDA version reported by nvcc.  That methodology isn't really unique or specific to CUDA. It's a very common paradigm in linux that the command interpreter searches the `PATH` var for many/most commands that you type, so formatting and ordering of the `PATH` var is certainly important. And regarding differences between what is reported by `nvcc` and what is reported by `nvidia-smi`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi/53504578#53504578) is probably relevant reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being partly a $PATH issue for `nvcc -V` to report correctly  and partly a library issue.

First the $PATH. This is a question of updating your $PATH variable to include your most current location of the CUDA Toolkit. nvidia-smi indicates that the correct driver is in place so you just need to make sure that the toolkit is present ie. does `/usr/local/cuda-xx.x` exist.  Two possibilities:

- if it exists then just modify your $PATH.  Easiest way is to look at the current path `echo $PATH`, then copy the entire output string to a text editor, change it so it includes `:/usr/local/cuda-xx.x/bin` (delete any old version if it exists), and then copy the changed string in to `export PATH=$PATH:<your new string>`.  Yes, you can just add to the path but if you do it this way you can see *exactly* what your path is and what has changed rather than just blindly adding to an existing path.
- if the toolkit of the version you want is not present then install it (see next item)

In this case the toolkit I was missing for library installations was 11.7.  After the driver installation I had `/usr/local/cuda-10.1` (old) which nvcc was reporting and `/usr/local/cuda-12.1` from the install but I needed 11.7.  Turns out multiple libraries can co-exist.  The solution was:

- install 11.7 with `sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-11-7`
- make sure it is discoverable with `export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/`