# getting incorrect cuda version after changing the $PATH

Tags: linux, pytorch, cuda

I want to know what is my cuda version so that I can install pytorch correctly.
To install pytorch I need to know what is my cuda version so I am doing as follow:

```
nvcc --version
```

but always I get this output

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

I have googled and found out that I need to modify my $PATH variable. via this stackoverflow link there is explanation to the similar issue.

[Getting CUDA version correctly reported by nvcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77245982/getting-cuda-version-correctly-reported-by-nvcc)
But still after modifying my $PATH and set the path to correct version of cuda and export it, I get still the same version output after running the `nvcc --version`.

I have checked in  `/usr/local/cuda-11.8` and I have this file. but I don't know why do I get the version 10 for cuda even if I have changed the $PATH.

I am using visual studio code with wsl ubuntu terminal

Comment: The PATH variable value is parsed from left to right, using the first instance of a command if finds.  Make sure you have the path to the version you want listed first.  You can use `which cuda`.  Now if you want to use `/usr/local/cuda-11.8`, you have to put /usr/local in your PATH before any other directory that contains cuda-11.8.  And you have to call it `cuda-11.8`.  If you call `cuda` it will not use that one.  The name has to be exact.